# Webcamoid installation

Tags: software-installation

How do I update webcamoid 8.8.0 to the newest release (9.0.0) from the terminal on Ubuntu 22.04? I have tried sudo apt update webcamoid and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt update` only updates the list of available software. You also need to run `sudo apt upgrade` to update your software.

However, **8.8.0 is already the most up-to-date version of this package in Ubuntu repositories**, so it will not be updated at this time.

It's usually not recommended to install versions of software that are different than those in repositories. For an explanation why, see [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283) In short, the versions of software in repositories are tested to work with your system. Other versions are not and may cause problems.

If you really need a newer version of the software, you'll need to obtain it from another source (usually the developer) and this will be at your own risk to your system and any collateral damage if there are incompatibilities with shared dependencies.

In this case, the developer publishes several releases as well as source code on [GitHub](https://webcamoid.github.io/). It looks like they offer an AppImage which is a self contained method of software distribution which is much less likely to interfere with the rest of your system. I say "less likely" because this AppImage still relies on dependencies in your system.  AppImages don't need to be installed. Just download it and execute it directly.

Related reading: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)

Comment: Thanks. This is quite informative. I will hold back for now.

Answer (score -1):

'update' only retrieves the package, I do not think it upgrades/installs it. If the command you tried before is successful then I suggest running "sudo apt install webcamoid". Hope this helps

Comment: `apt update` doesn't even do that. `apt update` updates the list of available software. It does not retrieve or update any packages. In addition, using the `install` argument would only be relevant if the package is not already installed. The question's author is asking how to update, though admittedly the details they provided are not very clear...

Comment: sudo apt upgrade doesn't do either. It returns a message that: webcamoid is already the newest version (8.8.0+dfsg-1). Thanks for the help.